# Clickhouse: calculate a difference between two dates excluding some days (but not the weekends!)

Tags: arrays, subquery, clickhouse

Maybe it's an easy problem, but I can't figure out how to solve it.
I'm working on ClickHouse 20.12.5.14.
My goal is to get the difference (in minutes) between two datetimes, excluding some days which are configured in a "non-working-days" table. Please notice that I'm not interested in excluding only Sundays and Saturdays: I should be able to exclude from the calculation only specific dates.

These are my tables (definitions at the end of the text):

```
select * 
from test_orders_workflow 
order by order_no, phase_no;

order_no|phase_no|phase_descr           |phase_date         |
--------|--------|----------------------|-------------------|
O_1342  |      10|Order placed          |2021-01-04 10:20:00|
O_1342  |      20|Payment processing    |2021-01-06 10:00:00|
O_1342  |      30|Order Fulfillment     |2021-01-08 11:00:00|
O_1342  |      40|Shipping and Delivery |2021-01-14 13:30:00|
O_6543  |      10|Order placed          |2021-02-03 15:00:00|
O_6543  |      20|Payment processing    |2021-02-03 17:30:00|
O_6543  |      25|Payment refused       |2021-02-03 17:33:00|
O_7836  |      10|Order placed          |2021-01-04 10:30:00|
O_7836  |      15|Order Cancelled       |2021-01-10 16:00:00|

select * from test_orders_nwd; 

not_w_day |
----------|
2021-01-01|
2021-01-07|
2021-02-01|
```

Of course, getting only the deltas is quite straightforward:

```
with t as (
select order_no, 
    arraySort(groupArray(phase_no)) phases_no, 
    arraySort((x,y) -> y, groupArray(phase_descr), phases_no) phases_descr, 
    arraySort((x,y) -> y, groupArray(phase_date), phases_no) phases_end, 
    arrayPushFront(arrayPopBack(phases_end), phases_end [1]) phases_begin, 
    arrayMap((x,y) -> trunc((x-y)/60), phases_end, phases_begin) phases_duration
    from test_orders_workflow
    group by order_no
)
select
    order_no,
    phases_no as phase_no,
    phases_descr as phase_descr,
    phases_begin as phase_begin,
    phases_end as phase_end,
    phases_duration as minutes 
from
    t 
array join phases_no,
    phases_descr,
    phases_begin,
    phases_end,
    phases_duration
order by
    order_no,
    phases_no;

order_no|phase_no|phase_descr           |phase_begin        |phase_end          |minutes|
--------|--------|----------------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------|
O_1342  |      10|Order placed          |2021-01-04 10:20:00|2021-01-04 10:20:00|    0.0|
O_1342  |      20|Payment processing    |2021-01-04 10:20:00|2021-01-06 10:00:00| 2860.0|
O_1342  |      30|Order Fulfillment     |2021-01-06 10:00:00|2021-01-08 11:00:00| 2940.0|
O_1342  |      40|Shipping and Delivery |2021-01-08 11:00:00|2021-01-14 13:30:00| 8790.0|
O_6543  |      10|Order placed          |2021-02-03 15:00:00|2021-02-03 15:00:00|    0.0|
O_6543  |      20|Payment processing    |2021-02-03 15:00:00|2021-02-03 17:30:00|  150.0|
O_6543  |      25|Payment refused       |2021-02-03 17:30:00|2021-02-03 17:33:00|    3.0|
O_7836  |      10|Order placed          |2021-01-04 10:30:00|2021-01-04 10:30:00|    0.0|
O_7836  |      15|Order Cancelled       |2021-01-04 10:30:00|2021-01-10 16:00:00| 8970.0|
```

but I can't figure out how to exclude from the difference the dates stored in the non-working-days definition. What I'm trying to get, is something like this (look at the third and last rows in the two last columns):

```
order_no|phase_no|phase_descr           |phase_begin        |phase_end          |minutes|working_minutes|
--------|--------|----------------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------|---------------|
O_1342  |      10|Order placed          |2021-01-04 10:20:00|2021-01-04 10:20:00|    0.0|            0.0|
O_1342  |      20|Payment processing    |2021-01-04 10:20:00|2021-01-06 10:00:00| 2860.0|         2860.0|
O_1342  |      30|Order Fulfillment     |2021-01-06 10:00:00|2021-01-08 11:00:00| 2940.0|         1500.0|
O_1342  |      40|Shipping and Delivery |2021-01-08 11:00:00|2021-01-14 13:30:00| 8790.0|         8790.0|
O_6543  |      10|Order placed          |2021-02-03 15:00:00|2021-02-03 15:00:00|    0.0|            0.0|
O_6543  |      20|Payment processing    |2021-02-03 15:00:00|2021-02-03 17:30:00|  150.0|          150.0|
O_6543  |      25|Payment refused       |2021-02-03 17:30:00|2021-02-03 17:33:00|    3.0|            3.0|
O_7836  |      10|Order placed          |2021-01-04 10:30:00|2021-01-04 10:30:00|    0.0|            0.0|
O_7836  |      15|Order Cancelled       |2021-01-04 10:30:00|2021-01-10 16:00:00| 8970.0|         7530.0|
```

My approach was to include in the query the count of non-working-days:

```
...
count(*)*24*60 from test_orders_nwd where not_w_day between the first and the second date
...
```

but it was unsuccessful, since Clickhouse doesn't allow you to include a subquery like this (without a join), neither in a standard query, nor using arrays. The following, for example, gives you an exception:

```
select order_no, phase_no, phase_descr, phase_begin, phase_end, minutes, 
minutes - (select count(*) 
            from test_orders_nwd tt
            where tt.not_w_day between phase_begin and phase_end
          )
from (
with t as (
select order_no, 
    arraySort(groupArray(phase_no)) phases_no, 
    arraySort((x,y) -> y, groupArray(phase_descr), phases_no) phases_descr, 
    arraySort((x,y) -> y, groupArray(phase_date), phases_no) phases_end, 
    arrayPushFront(arrayPopBack(phases_end), phases_end [1]) phases_begin, 
    arrayMap((x,y) -> trunc((x-y)/60), phases_end, phases_begin) phases_duration
    from test_orders_workflow
    group by order_no
)
select
    order_no,
    phases_no as phase_no,
    phases_descr as phase_descr,
    phases_begin as phase_begin,
    phases_end as phase_end,
    phases_duration as minutes
     
from
    t 
array join phases_no,
    phases_descr,
    phases_begin,
    phases_end,
    phases_duration
order by
    order_no,
    phases_no
);

--> 
ClickHouse exception, code: 47, host: 10.0.1.137, port: 8123; Code: 47, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'phase_end' 'phase_begin' while processing query: 'SELECT count() FROM test_orders_nwd AS tt WHERE (not_w_day >= phase_begin) AND (not_w_day <= phase_end)', required columns: 'not_w_day' 'phase_begin' 'phase_end', source columns: 'not_w_day': While processing (SELECT count(*) FROM test_orders_nwd AS tt WHERE (tt.not_w_day >= phase_begin) AND (tt.not_w_day <= phase_end)) AS _subquery13741024: While processing minutes - ((SELECT count(*) FROM test_orders_nwd AS tt WHERE (tt.not_w_day >= phase_begin) AND (tt.not_w_day <= phase_end)) AS _subquery13741024) (version 20.12.5.14 (official build))
```

and the same is when referencing the external table from the arrayMap function.

By the way, using a static array works fine, but I don't think it possible to compare the dates in the array with "x" and "y" in the lambda function:

```
select order_no, phase_no, phase_descr, phase_begin, phase_end, minutes, minutes_wd
from (
with t as (
with ['2021-01-04','2021-01-05'] as excluded_days
select order_no, 
    arraySort(groupArray(phase_no)) phases_no, 
    arraySort((x,y) -> y, groupArray(phase_descr), phases_no) phases_descr, 
    arraySort((x,y) -> y, groupArray(phase_date), phases_no) phases_end, 
    arrayPushFront(arrayPopBack(phases_end), phases_end [1]) phases_begin, 
    arrayMap((x,y) -> trunc((x-y)/60), phases_end, phases_begin) phases_duration,
    arrayMap((x,y) -> trunc((x-y - length(excluded_days)*24*60)/60) , phases_end, phases_begin) phases_duration_wd
    from test_orders_workflow
    group by order_no
)
select
    order_no,
    phases_no as phase_no,
    phases_descr as phase_descr,
    phases_begin as phase_begin,
    phases_end as phase_end,
    phases_duration as minutes,
    phases_duration_wd as minutes_wd
from
    t 
array join phases_no,
    phases_descr,
    phases_begin,
    phases_end,
    phases_duration,
    phases_duration_wd
order by
    order_no,
    phases_no
);
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance if you can help me.
Here you can find the definitions, in case you want to try:

```
create table test_orders_workflow 
(order_no String, phase_no Int8, phase_descr String, phase_date Datetime) engine = Log;  

insert into test_orders_workflow values 
('O_1342',10,'Order placed ',toDateTime('2021-01-04 10:20:00')),
('O_1342',20,'Payment processing',toDateTime('2021-01-06 10:00:00')),
('O_1342',30,'Order Fulfillment ',toDateTime('2021-01-08 11:00:00')),
('O_1342',40,'Shipping and Delivery ',toDateTime('2021-01-14 13:30:00')),
('O_7836',10,'Order placed ',toDateTime('2021-01-04 10:30:00')),
('O_7836',15,'Order Cancelled ',toDateTime('2021-01-10 16:00:00')),
('O_6543',10,'Order placed ',toDateTime('2021-02-03 15:00:00')),
('O_6543',20,'Payment processing',toDateTime('2021-02-03 17:30:00')),
('O_6543',25,'Payment refused',toDateTime('2021-02-03 17:33:00')); 

create table test_orders_nwd (not_w_day date) engine = Log; 

insert into test_orders_nwd values 
('2021-01-01'),
('2021-01-07'), 
('2021-02-01');
```

Comment: thank you for that you did not include create_table / insert. That was very helpful.

Comment: The create table and insert are at the end of the post. I'm sorry (seriously!) if I've done something wrong, but I can't get your remark. Maybe it was better I pasted them at the beginning of the question, and not at the end? It's my first post here, so please forgive me, in the future I will write down the object definitions at the beginning @DennyCrane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as (
select 
    (select groupArray(not_w_day) from test_orders_nwd) as gnot_w_day,
    order_no, 
    arraySort(groupArray(phase_no)) phases_no, 
    arraySort((x,y) -> y, groupArray(phase_descr), phases_no) phases_descr, 
    arraySort((x,y) -> y, groupArray(phase_date), phases_no) phases_end, 
    arrayPushFront(arrayPopBack(phases_end), phases_end [1]) phases_begin, 
    arrayMap((x,y) -> (trunc((x-y)/60), trunc((x-y)/60) - 24*60*length(arrayFilter(z -> z between y and x, gnot_w_day))), phases_end, phases_begin) phases_duration
    from test_orders_workflow
    group by order_no
)
select
    order_no,
    phase_no,
    phase_descr,
    phase_begin,
    phase_end,
    t_minutes.1 minutes,
    t_minutes.2 working_minutes 
from
    t 
array join phases_no as phase_no,
    phases_descr as phase_descr,
    phases_begin as phase_begin,
    phases_end as phase_end,
    phases_duration as t_minutes
order by
    order_no,
    phases_no;

┌─order_no─┬─phase_no─┬─phase_descr────────────┬─────────phase_begin─┬───────────phase_end─┬─minutes─┬─working_minutes─┐
│ O_1342   │       10 │ Order placed           │ 2021-01-04 10:20:00 │ 2021-01-04 10:20:00 │       0 │               0 │
│ O_1342   │       20 │ Payment processing     │ 2021-01-04 10:20:00 │ 2021-01-06 10:00:00 │    2860 │            2860 │
│ O_1342   │       30 │ Order Fulfillment      │ 2021-01-06 10:00:00 │ 2021-01-08 11:00:00 │    2940 │            1500 │
│ O_1342   │       40 │ Shipping and Delivery  │ 2021-01-08 11:00:00 │ 2021-01-14 13:30:00 │    8790 │            8790 │
│ O_6543   │       10 │ Order placed           │ 2021-02-03 15:00:00 │ 2021-02-03 15:00:00 │       0 │               0 │
│ O_6543   │       20 │ Payment processing     │ 2021-02-03 15:00:00 │ 2021-02-03 17:30:00 │     150 │             150 │
│ O_6543   │       25 │ Payment refused        │ 2021-02-03 17:30:00 │ 2021-02-03 17:33:00 │       3 │               3 │
│ O_7836   │       10 │ Order placed           │ 2021-01-04 10:30:00 │ 2021-01-04 10:30:00 │       0 │               0 │
│ O_7836   │       15 │ Order Cancelled        │ 2021-01-04 10:30:00 │ 2021-01-10 16:00:00 │    8970 │            7530 │
└──────────┴──────────┴────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────────────┘
```